# SQL Server 2014 command writing file to server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use either select or insert into a file to server? Such as this below I am using SQL Server 2014 on a Windows machine with DBO privileges. I don't want to use declare command is it possible to do it select or insert into to write asp or aspx file ?

With php this code is working how about SQL Server?

```
SELECT "some php code here" 
INTO OUTFILE " /var/www/website/public_html/somefile.php"
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=sql+server+write+query+results+to+file) are some ways you can do this.

Comment: I wanna do it with sql queries is it possible write asp or aspx file ?

Comment: `/var/www/website/public_html/somefile.php` is a linux file path, not a Windows filepath, SQL Server 2014 doesn't run on Linux (2017 was the first to). Are we missing something here?

Comment: Yes i want to write file "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.aspx" let's say how can i do it with sql command at mssql ?

Comment: Can i do it for example 

select "some asp code here" INTO OUTFILE " c:\inetpub\wwwroot\somefile.asp"

Comment: Have you tried anything? I gave you a link with a bunch of examples.

Comment: `With php this code is working` There isn't any PHP anywhere, only a SQL query.

Comment: Oh yes Thanks actually it writes creates php file from sql command to server i could not add php command as stackoverflow did not allow me .. What i want to do i wanna write an file at windows server with sql server 2014 with dbo privileges but i want to do it with select or insert into commands..

Answer (score 0):

By this way you should be able to write in a text file from Transact SQL code:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo I want to write this text in a Text file from SSMS and programatically > c:\output.aspx'
```

Be carefull with the special chars. You will need to scape them by inserting the ^ char just before the special char.

Otherwise, if your goal is to write the query results to a text file, the best way to do it, in my opinion, would be by using BCP command. (https://www.sqlshack.com/bcp-bulk-copy-program-command-in-action/)

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT * FROM MyTable" queryout "c:\output.csv" -w -t; -T -S MyServer'
```

Comment: Thanks for help mate but my point is actually there is running sql querie i just wanna add as second sql query to do it when i try to use your code i get this error "execution of non-query SQL statements is only available whe
n stacked queries are supported"

Comment: Show us how you tried and maybe we can be closer to knowing what you need

Comment: In sql query some private data might be leak is it possible to send you via email or PM somehow i could be really nice if you can check i looked at your profile could not see any contact details